# Shell script variable value not getting update

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to execute below bash shell script, but not getting the expected output. Possible i'm doing something wrong or it's not the way of doing this.

```
 #bin/bash
#set -x

path1_one=/home/dell/scripts
echo $path1_one
param_val=path1_one
param1=$( echo "$param_val" | awk -F '_' '{ print $0 }' )

#path2="$path1"
echo $param1

#echo $path2
```

**Output:**

/home/dell/scripts

path1_one

**Expected Output:**

/home/dell/scripts

/home/dell/scripts

Both variable value should be same,but don't know why param1 value is not reflecting with path1_one

Comment: Use `path2="$path1"`

Comment: It isn't obvious why you think your "expected" output is more correct than your actual output. `param_val=path1_one` assigns the *string* `path1_one` to `param_val`; why would anything "reflect"?

Comment: ...if you **want** indirect assignment or indirect expansion, we already have questions unambiguously asking how to do those things and with clear and readable answers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, param1=path1_one, so it should print the path1_one value which is /home/dell/scripts

Comment: use `param_val="$path1_one"` instead of `param_val=path1_one`. as everybody told you. they just used different variables to demonstrate that and expected you to adapt it to your script.

Comment: @subodh, no, `param1=path1_one` means that the **string** `path1_one` is stored in the variable `param1`. It **does not** mean that your variables have identical values or are references to each other.

Comment: @subodh, ...so, again: What do you expect or want to happen? If you want to look up the value of a variable named in a string, for instance, there **is** syntax to do so, and I'd be happy to mark this as duplicate of a question asking for that syntax. By contrast, if you want to establish a runtime linking -- ie. a "namevar" -- there's syntax for that too. But right now, it isn't established what mechanic you're aiming for.

Comment: @subodh, ...so, here's a question that'll help make the distinction. If after you've run `param_val=path1_one`, if someone then runs `param_val=two`, do you expect the value of the variable named `path1_one` to be `two`? If so, you want a namevar. If not, you want an indirect expansion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for your quick response,i think i need indirect expansion, you can mark this as duplicate with other question

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the script that you want to use the value of the variable `path1`, not the name `path1`.

Use:

```
path2="$path1"
```

Comment: NullDev,Thanks for your quick response, please see my updated complete script. please suggest me, how to get the value from path1.

Comment: still the same... `param_val="$path1"` but where is `path1_one` defined?

Comment: i'm expecting param1 to be path1_one value

Comment: Why do you expect that?